# WSP deployment issue in MOSS 2007

Tags: deployment, sharepoint-2007, wsp

We have a **WSP package** for deploying an application into MOSS 2007. After deploying the solution in to the **MOSS 2007**, none of the other sites working fine. Simply they are giving the "**Server Error in '/' Application**" error. If i retract the solution they working fine.

I have no idea, what could be issue. Can anybody please help me to find out the issue.

My WSP is just moving a DLL in to bin folder and one JavaScript file into Layouts folder.

Please help me to find out the issue.

Comment: Did you check the 12 hive logs?

Comment: I have checked it. Actually we figured out the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem is related to security. The DLL is not granted full trust. After we enable the full trust on the DLL everything started working fine.